# Zend Framework Plugin in INI is not run

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, configuration

The plugin declared in my application.ini file is not being triggered. I can install plugins the old way via the Bootstrap file, but I'd prefer to keep it in the INI. It doesn't ever load that file, no exception thrown, nothing.

I've tried adding `.class` to the declaration, but nothing.

`application.ini`

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
phpSettings.date.timezone = "America/Chicago"

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library:/Users/shane/Sites/doctrine1/lib"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
;resources.modules = ""

resources.frontcontroller.defaultmodule = default
resources.frontcontroller.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.doctrine.connections.default.dsn = "mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1/newfb"
resources.doctrine.manager.attributes.attr_model_loading = "model_loading_zend"
;resources.doctrine.manager.attributes.attr_use_native_enum = true
pluginpaths.ZFDoctrine_Application_Resource = "ZFDoctrine/Application/Resource"
autoloadernamespaces.0 = "Doctrine"
autoloadernamespaces.1 = "ZFDoctrine"
autoloadernamespaces.2 = "dummy"
autoloadernamespaces.3 = "ZFDebug"

resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = false

;; This should work, but it doesn't, not sure why
resources.frontController.plugins.messages = "dummy_Plugins_Messages"
```

`library/dummy/Plugins/Messages.php`

```
<?php

class dummy_Plugins_Messages extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
public function  preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
    parent::preDispatch($request);

    throw new Exception('HERE');

}
```

}

The `index.php` is the standard Zend_Application created using the Zend_Tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered the 'Faxxbachs_Plugins' namespace as a plugin path?

```
pluginpaths.Faxxbachs_Plugins = /path/to/Faxxbachs/Plugins
```

Also FYI, I noticed in your example, you were inconsistent in your casing of `frontController`. ZF tends gets whiny about case, so make sure you're consistent.

Comment: You are right on both accounts. After I fixed the case from `frontcontroller` to `frontController` and added the `pluginpaths` it started to work like a charm.  THANK YOU!